# size of a background image in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

I need to resize my window(`tkinter`) according to the width and height of my background image.
**My code**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2

image=cv2.imread("New_refImg.png")
width_1, height_1,channels = image.shape   

canvas = Canvas(width = width_1, height = height_1, bg = 'blue')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "New_refImg.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = img, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

I'm using a simple method, I call the same image twice : `image=cv2.imread("New_refImg.png")` and `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "New_refImg.png")` but is there a way change this line `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "New_refImg.png")` to something like that `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` (image already has been called in the 3rd line of the code)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PIL, but I can show you how to do it in tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # Create Tk before you can create an image

img = PhotoImage(file='pilner.png')
w, h = img.width(), img.height()   

canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg='blue', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

`highlightthickness=0` rmoves the highlight border on the canvas. I'm positioning it at 0,0 so as to not show the bg.

Comment: Thank you, but while testing your code I got an error : `TclError: image "pyimage118" doesn't exist` and I really don't understand this error!

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a missing reference. Are you sure you are running my exact code? And can you provide the error traceback please.

Comment: You may try to write `canvas.image = img` after the `create_image` statement, to keep a reference to the image.

Comment: yes of course, here you go :  
 `File "C:/Users/Akhou/Desktop//Img_Txt1.py", line 50, in <module>
    canvas.create_image(1, 1, image=img, anchor = NW)

  File "C:\Users\Akhou\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2483, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)`

  `File "C:\Users\Akhou\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2474, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))`

Comment: So, you get an error in line 50. My example does not have 50 lines, which means you aren't running my code. Can you show me your code please.

Comment: I added your code in an example that I'm working on, I commented the other code that I was working on and I added you code and run it and got that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171076/discussion-between-figbeam-and-a-khou).

Comment: Well, how code works often depend on what comes before and what comes after. Losing a reference usually means thet you have created the image inside a function. When the function exits the reference to the image is garbage collected. if you write canvas.image = img at the end of the function you should be ok. I'm off to lunch now so an answer might take a while.